# git checkout --merge <tree-ish> -- <paths> not working as expected

Tags: git, git-merge, git-checkout

When I try to merge my working tree changes to a file with the ones at `tree-ish` by checking its path out the former changes are overwritten with the latter changes.

I did not expect this behavior. Instead I would expect Git to replace the file content with conflict markers displayed in the *default*, *merge* or *diff3* style depending on whether the `--merge`, `--conflict=merge` or `--conflict=diff3` option was given to `git checkout`.

Given the following use case:

```
git init
echo foo > foobar
git add foobar
git commit --message=blabla foobar
echo bar > foobar
git checkout --conflict=diff3 HEAD -- foobar
```

I lose the local changes made with `echo bar > foobar`.

Also why does the manual page `git-checkout(1)` mention the `-m` and `--conflict=<style>` options in the synopsis `git checkout [-f|--ours|--theirs|-m|--conflict=<style>] [<tree-ish>] [--] <paths>…`? What is the purpose of these two options?

I use git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2 on Microsoft Windows 7.

Comment: I see why you expected that behavior -- the doc says "when checking out from the index" when describing the behavior you're getting, and this looks like a doc bug to me.  Notice that when describing the behavior you want, it says "when switching branches".  You're not doing either of those, so the doc doesn't actually say, but I'd read it exactly as you did.

Comment: But why shouldn't the same safety net apply as in the case of switching branches?

Comment: I think that, to describe what it's doing now accurately, the doc should just say "when checking out paths" and lose the "from the index" part, but I'd also argue for what you want, that "when checking out from a commit or tree [whether or not paths are specified]" for the merge behavior would be a better choice, and also that it should be changed to work that way (a course that's made easier to justify since the doc doesn't actually say what it's going to do here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see why you expected that behavior -- the doc says "when checking out paths from the index" when describing the behavior you're getting, and this looks like a doc bug to me. Notice that when describing the behavior you want, it says "when switching branches". I'd [mis]read that pair exactly as you did, and get surprised exactly the same way.

I think that, to describe what it's doing now accurately, the doc should just say "when checking out paths" and lose the "from the index" part, but I'd also argue for what you want, that "when checking out from a commit or tree [whether or not paths are specified]" for the merge behavior would be a better choice, and also that it should be changed to work that way -- a course that's made easier to justify since atm the doc doesn't actually say what it's going to do here

Answer (score 0):

That should change with Git 2.22 (Q2 2019).

"`git checkout -m <other>`" was about carrying the differences between HEAD and the working-tree files forward while checking out another branch, and ignored the differences between HEAD and the index.

The command has been taught to abort when the index and the
HEAD are different.

See [commit 6eff409](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6eff409e8a760645ae5357d1e95e7e7ff3c04456), [commit 3e41485](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e41485d856dab4589f25759a367091e40a95cb3), [commit b165fac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b165fac8c1970e9cc9e5a0715a2f06b3530b2570), [commit 191e9d2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/191e9d2c2dac2aaf8cb7db854cec48028addfece) (22 Mar 2019) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4a3ed2b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a3ed2bec6031545aea38db10e443a979951346f), 25 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### `checkout`: prevent losing staged changes with `--merge`
>
> When --merge is specified, we may need to do a real merge (instead of
>   three-way tree unpacking), the steps are best seen in git-checkout.sh
>   version before it's removed:

```sh
    # Match the index to the working tree, and do a three-way.
    git diff-files --name-only | git update-index --remove --stdin &&
    work=`git write-tree` &&
    git read-tree $v --reset -u $new || exit

    git merge-recursive $old -- $new $work

    # Do not register the cleanly merged paths in the index yet.
    # this is not a real merge before committing, but just carrying
    # the working tree changes along.
    unmerged=`git ls-files -u`
    git read-tree $v --reset $new
    case "$unmerged" in
    '')     ;;
    *)
            (
                    z40=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    echo "$unmerged" |
                    sed -e 's/^[0-7]* [0-9a-f]* /'"0 $z40 /"
                    echo "$unmerged"
            ) | git update-index --index-info
            ;;
    esac
```

> Notice the last '`read-tree --reset`' step.
>   We restore worktree back to 'new' tree after worktree's messed up by merge-recursive.
>   If there are staged changes before this whole command sequence is executed, they
>   are lost because they are unlikely part of the 'new' tree to be restored.
>
> There is no easy way to fix this. [Elijah may have something up his
>   sleeves](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10859205/), but until then, check if there are staged changes and
>   refuse to run and lose them. The user would need to do "`git reset`" to
>   continue in this case.

Comment: Thanks for this update! I see the doc still says `When switching branches with --merge, staged changes may be lost.` - do I understand correctly / do you agree that a doc change is needed here, that this change eliminated that potential for data loss? (although the command is still of dubious value in its current state, I would argue)

Comment: @Tao Well, they may be lost if you chose to go on with the checkout. That is why now the checkout will stop with `cannot continue with staged changes in the following file`

Comment: Hmm... but the checkout will abort, right? So the staged changes *would* be lost if you did something that checkout is now refusing to do (unless you pass some further flag to force, I assume). Sorry, I feel I'm missing a subtlety here. The doc right now screams (very quietly) "-m is unsafe", but the changes you describe here *appear* to mean this is no longer true.

Comment: @Tao I agree, this is confusing. Since that change (https://github.com/git/git/blame/master/builtin/checkout.c#L806=), I don't see any other more recent commit which would clarify that.